# c++ segmentation error: Why this program gives Runtime Error(SIGSEGV)

Tags: c++, runtime-error, segmentation-fault

**This code runs well in codeblocks but gives Runtime(SIGSEGV) error in codechef's compiler**
Please go through the code below and tell the solution to this error.Thank You.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
int t;
long n;
cin>>t;
while(t--){
    cin>>n;
    int i=2,m=0,j=0,a[n/2];
    while(i<=n/2){
        if(n%i==0){
            n=n/i;
            a [ j++ ] = i;
            m++;
            i = 2;

        }
        else i++;
        a[j] = n;
    }
    cout << m+1 << endl;
    for(int i=0;i<=m;i++)
        cout << a[i] <<  endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Have you looked up what a Segfault is caused by?

Comment: Where is it failing, whats your efforts to fix this?

Comment: I don't see any segmentation fault in this code. but I think it's worth the mention that in some compilers you need to give constant value to declare an array otherwise it will give you compiler error.

Comment: A raw array declaration is not standard C++ when the number of elements is not a constant expression (e.g. `a[n/2]` where `n` is not a constant expression). This may be causing the problem, but either way it is not standard and should be avoided (and one reason why C++ has container classes).

Comment: @crashmstr If a raw array  cannot be declared in standard C++ when the number of elements is not a constant expression then please suggest method to that using classes...

Comment: `std::vector` is the common way  in C++ to represent a collection of objects whose number is not known until runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error caused by an invalid memory reference or segmentation fault. The most common causes are accessing an array element out of bounds, or using too much memory.

Some things for you to try:

Make sure you aren't using variables that haven't been initialised. These may be set to 0 on your computer, but aren't guaranteed to be on the judge.

Check every single occurrence of accessing an array element and see if it could possibly be out of bounds.

Make sure you aren't declaring too much memory. 64 MB is guaranteed, but having an array of size [10000][10000] will never work.

Make sure you aren't declaring too much stack memory. Any large arrays should be declared globally, outside of any functions - putting an array of 100000 ints inside a function probably won't work.

**for overcome this problem try to use static memory allocation.**

**Some of the other causes of a segmentation fault are :**

1. Using uninitialized pointers
2. dereference of NULL pointers
3. accessing memory that the program doesn’t own.

you will find more details about segmentation fault here. [click here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)

***Also check your while loop code.***

Comment: Thanks very much but I found this kind of theory on the web earlier also. Please tell  me why the code in this program is giving such type of error. Also how can I correct it .